# Duplicate of Action on Google with a different name

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant

Does Google allow to release to production the same Action on Google (same logic, same content) for the second time? I'd like to test discoverability of one of my actions, but I don't want to change the name of the existing one (it's got paid subscribers who got used to the old name). So launching a duplicate with a new name makes sense from my point of view, but I don't want to waste my time in case it violates Google Assistant policy.

Comment: Reading [the policies](https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/policies/general-policies) I don't see anything that stands out, although it may appear at first glance to be some kind of impersonation.

Answer (score 0):

***Technically*** I think you might be in violation of the [Repetitive Content](https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/policies/general-policies#repetitive_content) section, which includes:

> We don't allow Actions that merely provide the same experience as other Actions already on the Actions on Google platform. Actions should provide value to users through the creation of unique content or services.
>
> Here are some examples of violations:
>
> Creating multiple Actions with highly similar functionality, content, and user experience. If these Actions are each small in content volume, developers should consider creating a single Action that aggregates all the content.

I don't know if they'd actually catch this, however. And aggregating content wouldn't make sense in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to AoG Support team and they confirmed that it would be a violation of Repetitive Content policy. Not sure how to test what invocation name works best for my app in this case...